# Where is a responsum regarding misguided Jews prioritizing kisui rosh over observance of kashrus?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, priorities, responsa, yarmulke, levush

I'm having trouble tracking down a teshuvah where it is mentioned that some folks used to prioritize kisui rosh which isn't halachically mandated while not keeping kashrus and poked fun at others that did the reverse

(Maharshal?)

Anyone know where it is?